# Suspension not shown properly on meta

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, account-suspension

Looking at this picture:

[image]

You can see the following:

In main the suspension message states:

> This account is temporarily suspended **for rule violations**. The suspension period ends in 3 days.

In meta the suspension message states:

> This account is temporarily suspended. The suspension period ends in 3 days.

You see the highlighted part. Why is it missing in meta?

---

(I am not giving a link, as I do not want to blame any user.)

Comment: Also reported on MSE in 2016: [Suspension reason shows on main, but not on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280130/335251)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's **not possible** to suspend people on Meta Stack Overflow. The option to send a moderator message (which is necessary to suspend a user) is grayed out on child Meta sites. Therefore, a user is always suspended on the *main* site, and the sole reason why this user is suspended on Meta is that they've been suspended on the main site; the actual reason is irrelevant and is (probably) not even *stored* in the database of the Meta site. Then, not showing the reason on Meta saves another database call which leads to better performance. Don't we all love that?

Comment: Ok, so it is probably [status-bydesign].

Comment: @Glorfindel I don't think the database is that slow...

Comment: @user202729: Who cares how slow it is? An avoided call to the database is always relevant, and as the information is useless here (because the one and only reason a user can be suspended here is through a suspension at SO main), there is no point in retrieving that information.

Comment: I don't buy the "database call" argument as this should be utterly trivial - however, socially, I do agree that this banner would be at best misleading because no rule violation _on meta_ led to the suspension. Mind you, I'm not sure how you can be suspended for anything other than rule violations anyway so whatever

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm pretty sure I've seen "This account is temporarily suspended to cool down" before, or something like that.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder: Yep those exist - I was sort of joking - if you need to cool down you probably broke a rule :P

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Fair enough, I'll go and tune my joke/sarcasm radar for future use.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder: Just set it to turn on automatically whenever I'm blathering on about anything :)

Comment: @Glorfindel: something else I just saw. Is there any reason why the "time left" message does not show the exact date on hover (unlike all other time stamps on StackExchange)?

Comment: @MEE I don't know (it might have been asked before, possibly on [meta.se]), but for longer suspensions it does show the exact date and time, e.g. "The suspension period ends on Jun 29 at 20:48."

Comment: @Glorfindel ok, couldn't find something on MSE, but I don't think it is so important...